# Problems with obtaining the Firebase storage reference

Tags: javascript, firebase, polymer, firebase-storage

I have a problem getting the storage reference even though I configured the firebase-app according to documentation. The firebase-app element is located in the index.html

```
<firebase-app name="name-of-the-app"
              api-key="api_key"
              auth-domain="name-of-the-app.firebaseapp.com"
              database-url="https://name-of-the-app.firebaseio.com"
              storage-bucket="name-of-the-app.appspot.com">
</firebase-app>
```

I am accessing the app reference in the subviews the following way:

```
<firebase-document id="office_document"
                   app-name="doctor-appointment-system"
                   path="/offices">
</firebase-document>
<script>
  this.$.office_document.app.storage()
</script>
```

The code above is throwing the an error.

> this.$.office_document.storage is not a function

The database counterpart works ok.

```
this.$.office_document.app.database()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't have firebase storage script imported in my index.html, where the app was initialized with firebase-app element.

Here is what my imports look like now:

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-app.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-storage-script.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-document.html">
```